# How to fix broken ngModel after allowing contenteditable for a button?

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

Template:

```
<button *ngFor="name of students"
        (click)="modifyText($event.currentTarget)">{{name}}</button>
```

TypeScript

```
this.students = ["Carl", "Rob", "Joy];
public modifyText(htmlElement: HTMLElement) {
    this.dataset.edit = !this.dataset.edit;
    htmlElement.contentEditable = this.dataset.edit;
    htmlElement.focus();
}
```

The problem is, as soon as I modify the content with content-editable, I seem to lose the binding to {{name}}, as if I have a separate button on the page:

```
<button (click)="students[0] = 'Amy'">Manual Set Name</button>
```

The students array changes, but when I look at the text of the button, it is what I had "edited" in contenteditable, and does not show Amy at all.

Comment: Do you really need to use the HtmlElement as shown? Or can you do it the *Angular* way and instead bind to the [disabled] property of the element in the HTML?

Comment: I need to because I only want it to be content editable on click. Am open to alternative ways of achieving the same functionality if you have suggestions or this is not possible.

Comment: Can you do a plunker that demonstrates the basics what what you are trying to do so we have something to work with?

Comment: I don't see `ngModel` anywhere in your code

Comment: It is assumed that the component the Template is in has a "students" variable on it. So it is already bound. Unless you are suggesting that ngModel would get around this problem?

Comment: I agree that there is probably a more "Angular" way to do this, but you could always just pass `name` to your `modifyText` method in the markup. i.e. `<button *ngFor="name of students"
        (click)="modifyText($event.currentTarget, name)">{{name}}</button>`

Comment: You dont need to set the `contentEditable` property from the controller. You can set it to a variable using `[attr.contenteditable]="bla"` directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `ngModel` and [pure Angular two ways data binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way) in an embedded component :

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'editable-button',
  template: `
    <button *ngIf="!editable" (click)="editable = true">{{title}}</button>
    <input *ngIf="editable" (blur)="editTitle()" [(ngModel)]="title">
  `,
})
export class EditableButtonComponent {

  @Input() title: string;
  @Output() titleChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  editable= false;

  editTitle() {
    this.editable = false;
    this.titleChange.emit(this.title);
  }
}
```

And then your template will look like the following :

```
<editable-button *ngFor="let name of students; let index=index" [(title)]="students[index]"></editable-button>
```

Note I'm using the index of the element in place of it's reference. Here you could see an explaination : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10423

Working stylized Plunker example here : https://plnkr.co/edit/eia5PYp3Z5F6WRcWpMeA?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure where is your error is. Here is my simple way to write this component.

https://plnkr.co/edit/DpOzFIEeRZ05n64mWnvL

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div>
        here is value = {{value}}
        <button [attr.contenteditable]="contenteditable" #el
             (click)="open(el)" 
             (blur)="close(el)" 
            (keyup.enter)="close(el)">{{value}}</button>
      </div>
    `,
  })
  export class App {
    value ="aaa";
    contenteditable = false;

    constructor() {
    }
    open(el) {
      this.contenteditable = true;
      setTimeout(()=>el.focus());
    }
    close(el) {
      this.contenteditable = false;
      this.value = el.innerText;
    }
  }
```